# react fetching data when route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, router

I have some routes and I want to fetch data on the client side when each route changes.

I call the fetch function in `componentDidMount` as follows:

> componentDidMount() {
>           this.props.fetchSubmitInitialData(); }

But in `render()` function I can't access the new Redux props.

Comment: Because fetch is an asynchronous action, your component will render without data until response has been completed and updated your redux state, a possible solution is to place a spinner until the response has been completed and then render the content you want to show

Comment: thanks. but how I recognize the data has been received in render function? @JoseAPL

Comment: You have to save the response in the redux store let's say `submitInitialData`, and then get that store in your page component. So the first time it will be an empty object, but once the response is completed you have to trigger the `successAction` and in the reducer set the given response to the `submitInitialData`

Comment: thanks a lot! @JoseAPL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how I recognize the data has been received in render function

In a sense you don't recognize that data has been received, your render function simply renders the view for any state. It's just that the state (or props passed from the redux state store) change when data is received. So the next time `render()` is called it runs against the updated values and gives you an updated view of the current state.

Here's a chronological example:

Suppose your initial state looks like this

```
state:
  loading: true
  loaded: false
  data: null
```

So at this stage when the component renders, the `state.loading` is `true`, so you may display a Loading... message for example

When the component is mounted, you fetch the data, so a call happens and data is returned, and the state is updated to e.g.

```
state:
   loading: false
   loaded: true
   data: {'hello': 'world'}
```

Now your render function sees that `state.loaded` is `true`, so it can proceed to render a view for the data in `state.data`